# got error in firefox while using document.open()

Tags: javascript

I can now open Iframes with javascript to write content into it. It gives me a security error, since i do not use any cross-site stuff.

I create the Iframe with javascript, and I want to write into it with same javascript.

CODE:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write("htmlcontent");
doc.close();
```

ERROR in firefox:

> Exception: Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location:"unknown"

working fine in IE

Please let me know the solution for the above error.

Comment: Could you please post some of your code, so we can see what might cause this?

Comment: It's `.write` and not `.writer`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. try to add parent body.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe")

// add this
iframe.style.display = 'none'; // if you want
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
// add this

var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write("htmlcontent");
doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
```

In Firefox, `iframe.contentDocument` and `iframe.contentWindow` are `null` before you insert the iframe to page, document readyState is `"uninitialized"` but not `"complete"`(like other browsers), you should waiting for the onload or DOMContentLoaded events.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = 'none'; // if you want
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
if(doc.readyState == 'complete'){
    doc.open();
    doc.write("htmlcontent");
    doc.close();
}else{
    iframe.contentWindow.onload = function(){
        doc.open();
        doc.write("htmlcontent");
        doc.close();
    };
}
```